# Suppress error output (sometimes) in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a batch file to delete all network mappings and then remap.
In the first section where any current mappings are deleted, if a mapping does not exist and it tries to delete it, it outputs an error message "The network path was not found". I don't want to see these, but then I do want to see any errors that occur in the second part where it does the mapping. How do I do this?

```
echo delete all mappings

net use A: /delete
net use B: /delete
net use C: /delete
net use D: /delete
net use E: /delete
net use F: /delete
net use G: /delete
net use H: /delete
net use I: /delete
net use J: /delete
net use K: /delete
net use L: /delete
net use M: /delete
net use N: /delete
net use O: /delete
net use P: /delete
net use Q: /delete
net use R: /delete
net use S: /delete
net use T: /delete
net use U: /delete
net use V: /delete
net use W: /delete
net use X: /delete
net use Y: /delete
net use Z: /delete

echo set mappings

net use G: \\mynetw-nas\GIS1
net use I: \\mynetw-nas\ITO
```

Comment: I was not aware that **MS-DOS** (the OS from the 1980s) supported UNC paths... please revise the tags..

Comment: @aschipfl I love your sarcastic MS-DOS remarks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
echo delete all mappings

2>nul (net use A: /delete
net use B: /delete
net use C: /delete
etc...)

echo set mappings

net use G: \\mynetw-nas\GIS1
net use I: \\mynetw-nas\ITO
```

note that `2>nul` redirects error output to prevent it from showing

Answer (score 1):

why iterate through 26 letters?

```
net use * /delete /y
```

NOTE: to try it out, use it without `/y` - then there is a security (Y/N) prompt

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, IMO this should be a comment

Comment: @DennisvanGils why not? This does not try to delete non-existent mappings - so there are no error messages.

Comment: @Stephan sorry, I didn't know this only tried the mapped drives, I thought this simply was a shorter way of net use A-Z /delete, hence why I thought it would still give error messages.